# Originally declared as constant confusion

Tags: c++, constants, const-cast

> `const_cast` is safe only if you're casting a variable that was originally non-const.

Are literals the only data that was originally declared as constant? If not can anyone please give example of originally declared const data scenario?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357600/is-const-cast-safe (see accepted answer)

Comment: @llya I have asked the question after reading the thread you mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not just literals are originally declared as const. *Any* object which is declared as const is "originally const".

```
const int this_is_a_const_int = 10;
const std::string this_is_a_const_string = "this is a const string";

std::string this_is_not_a_const_string;
std::cin >> this_is_not_a_const_string;

const std::string but_this_is = this_is_not_a_const_string;
```

What's *not* originally const is when you have a const reference to a non-const object

```
int n;
std::cin >> n;

const int & const_int_ref = n;
int& int_ref = const_cast<int&>(const_int_ref); // this is safe, because const_int_ref refers to an originally
                                                // non-const int
```

Comment: That is what I meant. Objects initialized with literals are originally declared const right?

Comment: @Tahlil: No. It doesn't matter what it is initialized with.

Comment: @Tahlil adding to that, it only matters that it *is* initialized (it must be, as it is `const`). Once initialization is finished, `const` is firm. But that much I *think* you already knew. (+1, btw).