# About move a const object

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I know `std::move` A const Object will actually invoke `T`'s copy constructor,
So I want to do some Experiments of implementation of my move and inner of this remove to remove `const` such like :

```
template<typename _Tp>
typename std::remove_const<typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type>::type&&
my_move(_Tp&& __t) noexcept {
    using removed_reference = typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type;
    using removed_ref_const = typename std::remove_const<removed_reference>::type;
    return static_cast<removed_ref_const&&>(__t);
}
```

but This code will not compile?  Why

And If I change the order of `remove_reference` and `remove_const`, This code will compile but not as my expect,  `my_move(const Object T)` still uses Object `T`'s copy constructor?

And Also who can give me a right implementation which will show when I remove `const`, This will use `T`'s move constructor.

T may be as:

```
struct T
{
    T() = default;
    T(const T&) { std::cout << "copy ctor\n"; }
    T(T&&)      { std::cout << "move ctor\n"; }
};

int main() {
    const T t;
    T a = my_move(t);
}
```

Comment: Ok I didn't read this in detail, but if your code modifies the state of `t`, then it is wrong, as `t` is const.

Comment: Please let us know what made you think that attempting this is safe at all. A `move` will modify the non-const source. That's the whole point of it. If that source can be modified, it shouldn't be const in the first place. Please amend your question with a description of what higher-level problem you're trying to solve. Perhaps that underlying issue has a better solution than what you propose here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the constness of an object, the cast to use is `const_cast` and not `static_cast`

Do you want something like :

```
template<typename T>
T&& my_move(const T& t) noexcept {
    return std::move(const_cast<T&>(t));
}
```

(with the possible problems to remove `const` from object)...

[Live example](http://ideone.com/ZXcVku)

Comment: This is a straightforward way, but how to do this in the inner implementation of move ?

Comment: By changing your `static_cast` by `const_cast` your code compile... but using `const_cast` this way may lead to UB.

Comment: I found here remove_const only can remove top level const, since t passed to my_move is a lvalue, It's resolved as rvalue reference, so may be remove_const can't remove the const?

Comment: `remove_const` remove `const` for the *type* not the **value**, so in your version you have `static_cast<T&&>(t)` where `t` is `const T&`.

Comment: and why use const_cast may lead to Undefined Behavior?

Comment: @bryantism: you may look at [is-const-cast-safe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357600/is-const-cast-safe)