# Try to modify const reference

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

I've got an argument with my co-workers. 
Once I did try to modify constant reference.

Sample of code is below:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
   const int* A = NULL;

   printf("A = %p\n", A);

   int** pA = const_cast<int**>(&A);

   *pA = new int(5);

   if (pA != NULL)
      printf("pA = %p, value = %d\n", pA, *pA);
   else
      printf("pA null pointer\n");

   if (A != NULL)
      printf("A = %p, value = %d\n", A, *A);
   else
      printf("A null pointer\n");

   return 0;
}
```

Everything works fine and the log is

```
 A = 00000000
 pA = 0028FED8, value = 4068760
 A = 003E1598, value = 5
```

I think it works that way:

1. I create a const pointer variable A with '0' (zero) value is stack. It is local variable wich occupies 4 bytes of memory in stack.
2. then I create a pointer to pointer variable, I cast away constant modification and take address of the variable

I think this code works fine and will not lead to a bug. But I need some kind of explanations. Am I right?

Comment: 1. You created a pointer to `const`. It is OK to modify `A`, not the thing it points to.

Answer (score 3):

`const int *a` and `int * const a` are different.

#### Case 1

[`const` is used on `*a`]

Here the **value** of `a` is constant. The address pointed by `a` can be changed.

```
const int *a = malloc(sizeof (int));
if (a)
{
  //*a = 10;                    //not allowed
  a = malloc(sizeof (int));;   //allowed
}
```

#### Case 2

[`const` is used on `a`]

Here the **address** of `a` is constant. The value of `a` can be changed.

```
int * const a = malloc(sizeof (int));
if (a)
{
  *a = 10;                      //allowed
  //a = malloc(sizeof (int));;    //not allowed
}
```

---

**EDIT**:

As suggested by @lifeOfPI, read about using [`const_cast`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357600/is-const-cast-safe) .

Comment: would be a perfect answer if it explains `const_cast<>` and possible resulting undefined behaviors as it was used in sample code, anyway +1