# Is it safe to remove const via const_cast and invoke a non-const function that does not modify the resulting object?

Tags: c++, const-cast

I know that casting away `const`-ness should be done with care, and any attempt to remove `const`-ness from an initially `const` object followed by modifying the object results in undefined behaviour. What if we want to remove `const`-ness so that we may invoke a non-const function which doesn't modify the object? I know that we should actually mark such function `const`, but suppose I'm using a "bad" code that doesn't have the `const` version available.

So, to summarize, is the code below "safe"? My guess is that as long as you don't end up modifying the object you're ok, but I'm not 100% sure.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    void f() // doesn't modify the instance, although is not marked const
    {
        std::cout << "Foo::f()" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    const Foo foo;
    const_cast<Foo&>(foo).f(); // is this safe?
}
```

Comment: Regardless of the fact that it's allowed by the standard, as answered already, I would say it's neither safe nor okay.

Comment: @hvd Why would a read-only operation be unsafe?

Comment: @Barry That's not the point. That member function can be modified later, to accidentally invoke UB.

Comment: @hvd I've seen code like this in some proxy class implementation, where the ctor was taking a non-const param. The usage came in a function that was returning a const proxy, but had to invoke the non-const ctor to construct the proxy. Quite obfuscated, but nevertheless real code. And yes, I know one shouldn't write such code, I was just curios if technically it is ok.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it allowed to cast away const on a const-defined object as long as it is not actually modified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54504247/is-it-allowed-to-cast-away-const-on-a-const-defined-object-as-long-as-it-is-not)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Undefined behavior with respect to `const_cast` is defined by the C++11 standard's **§3.8/9** (§3.8 is “Object lifetime”):

> **”** Creating a new object at the storage location that a `const` object with static, thread, or automatic storage duration occupies or, at the storage location that such a `const` object used to occupy before its lifetime ended results in undefined behavior.

and **§7.1.6.1/4** (§7.1.6.1 is “The *cv-qualifiers*”)

> **”** Except that any class member declared `mutable` (7.1.1) can be modified, any attempt to modify a `const`
>   object during its lifetime (3.8) results in undefined behavior.

In other words, you get UB if you modify an ***originally `const`*** object, and otherwise <sup>1</sup>not.

The `const_cast` itself doesn't introduce UB.

---

There is additionally a non-normative note at **§5.2.11/7** that “depending on the type” a write through the pointer or reference obtained from a `const_cast`, may have undefined behavior.

This non-normative note is so wooly that it has its own non-normative footnote, that explains that “`const_cast` is not limited to conversions that cast away a `const`-qualifier.”.

However, still with that clarification I fail to think of any case where the write could be well-defined or not depending on the type, i.e., I fail to make sense of this note. Two other answers here focus on the word “write” in this note, and that's necessary to get into UB-land via §3.8/9, yes. The to me rather fishy aspect is the “depending on the type”, which appears to be the significant part of that note.

---

<sup><sup>1)</sup> Except insofar as UB-rules about other non-`const_cast`-related things get into play, e.g. nulling a pointer that's later dereferenced in a context other than as `typeid`-expression.</sup>

Comment: There's also: 7.1.6.1 "Except that any class member declared mutable (7.1.1) can be modified, any attempt to modify a const object during its lifetime (3.8) results in undefined behavior."

Comment: "Depending on the type" makes sense if it refers to the type used when defining the object. A `const`-qualifier used in the definition is part of the type, and whether modifications are allowed depends on whether that qualifier was used.

Comment: @hvd: Thanks, that makes sense. A kind of twisted sense since they could just have written that. Still, I think that's a likely explanation. :)

Answer (score 7):

This particular example happens to be safe (have well defined behavior) because there is no *write* to an object which is declared `const`.

Comment: so as long as there's no "write" it's safe, right? That's what I thought.

Comment: Exactly, a write happens when the bytes forming the representation of the object are written to.

Answer (score 6):

We have this in [dcl.type.cv]:

> Except that any class member declared `mutable` (7.1.1) can be modified, any attempt to modify a `const` object during its lifetime (3.8) results in undefined behavior.

And there is a note (non-normative) in [expr.const.cast] which states:

> *[Note:* Depending on the type of the object, a **write operation** through the pointer, lvalue or pointer
>   to data member resulting from a `const_cast` that casts away a *const-qualifier* may produce undefined
>   behavior (7.1.6.1). *—end note ]*

An attempt to modify an object or a write operation after a `const_cast` [may] result in undefined behavior. Here, we have no write operation.