# Why is a cast `int**const` to `const int**const` forbidden

Tags: c++, casting, const-cast

The following is allowed:

```cpp
    int * const p1 = nullptr;
    auto p2 = static_cast< const int * const >( p1 );
```

In my understanding `p1` is a *"const-ptr to int"*, which is casted to a
*"const-ptr to const-int"*.

Why is the following forbidden

```cpp
    int * * const pp1 = nullptr;
    auto pp2 = static_cast< const int * * const >( pp1 );
```

In my understanding `pp1` is a *"const-ptr to ptr to int"* which shall be casted to a *"const-ptr to ptr to const-int"*. Thus I am adding `const`, so I would think it is allowed.

Comment: Do you get any error? Always post complete error(if any) along with your question.

Comment: Btw  you have 2 typos. Instead of `ptr` it should be `p1` and `pp1`

Comment: `int** const` is a constant pointer to a non-constant pointer to a non-constant  `int`. `const int** const` is a constant pointer to a non-constant pointer to a constant `int`. They are not the same types.

Comment: *"Thus I am adding const, so I would think it is allowed...."* If that were the case,  you should've use `const_cast`.

Comment: If you're looking for an authoritative answer, kindly add `language-lawyer` tag.

Comment: @user12002570 `const_cast` is used to remove `const`.

Comment: The second const is irrelevant for this matter

Comment: @tommsch No, on the contrary. It is used to add `const`. Granted you can use it to remove `const` also, but still any attempt to modify a const object is undefined behavior. [Is it safe to remove const via const_cast and invoke a non-const function that does not modify the resulting object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29883327/is-it-safe-to-remove-const-via-const-cast-and-invoke-a-non-const-function-that-d)

Comment: The same problem happens from `int**` to the `const int**`. Which is `int const* *` in sane notation). (edited, misunderstood a comment)

Comment: Are you trying to implement a multidimensional array? If yes, there are better ways even if you make this work eventually.

Comment: not sure if it would have helped here, but [cool stuff](https://cdecl.org/?q=const+int+**+const+x%3B)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though it *looks like* you're only adding `const`, you can use the resulting pointer to **remove** constness (a `const_cast` in disguise). Observe:

```
int **const pp1 = nullptr;
auto pp2 = (const int **const)pp1;

const int x = 42;
*pp2 = &x;
**pp1 = 43; // Modifying `x` = undefined behavior.
```

Note that, on the other hand, casting to `const int *const *` (and `const int *const *const`) is allowed.