# conversion between 2 types with different const qualifiers

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, const-cast, template-classes

This is a short example of the code I want to use:

```
template <class T>
class B
{
public :
    bool func1(const T& t)
    {
        // do something
    }
};


class A
{
    B<int*> b;
public:
    void func2(const int* a)
    {
        b.func1(a);
    }
};
```

I'm getting this error :

**error C2664: 'B::func1' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const int *' to 'int *const &'**

is a way to solve this without changing the functions declarations and without using const_cast?

**Edit:**

some information behind the problem

1. `B` is actually a container class I wrote (lets say a list)
2. `A` is a class using that list
3. `func1` is a function that need to find if an element is in the list or not
4. `func2` is a function that recieves an element to remove from the list

Comment: What do you want `T` deduced as in that case?

Comment: int*  (as in parameter b in class A)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the reference to the const pointer, then try this:

```
B<const int*> b;
```

---

If you know *for sure* that what you are passing in is not originally a `const int *` (that is, you originally have an `int *` and it turned into a `const int *` somewhere along the way), then you can do this:

```
b.func1(const_cast<int *>(a));
```

Note that this can [easily lead to undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357600/is-const-cast-safe) if the precondition I mentioned is not met. And it's confusing because the user of a function would not expect the function to change what is pointed to by the pointer. Better to pass in an `int *` from the get-go:

```
void func2(int* a) 
{
    b.func1(a);
}
```

---

Based on your [latest comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33111091/conversion-between-2-types-with-different-const-qualifiers/33111130?noredirect=1#comment54037050_33111130), I think this is what you want:

```
template <class T>
class B
{
    typedef typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type base_type;
    typedef typename std::add_const<base_type>::type const_base_type;
    typedef typename std::add_pointer<const_base_type>::type pointer_const_base_type;
public :
    void func1(const pointer_const_base_type& t)
    {
        std::cout << t << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Given `T = base_type *`, I laboriously build up `pointer_const_base_type = const base_type *`. Now `func1` takes a reference to that `const base_type *`. Note this assumes that `T` is a pointer to something; you'll have to fiddle with it more to work for non-pointers.

Comment: but if you notice parameter b in class A is B<int*>
so func1 need to use int* as T and sending *a will sent int as you mentioned

Comment: @Jinxed: Do you want to take a const reference to the pointer, or do you want to take a const reference to the int itself?

Comment: @Jinxed: How about this one? Give the type as `const int*`. Otherwise it wants a reference to a non-const `int `*, and you can't pass in a `const int *` to that, as you found out.

Comment: @Claudio: I need the type to stay as int in order to change the ints later on the code

Comment: @Jinxed: Then you effectively want to const_cast away the `const` of the `const int *`, which can lead to undefined behavior if it was const to begin with. Your `func2` will have to take a regular `int *`.

Comment: @Jinxed: That you can never do through the pointer `a`, since the whole purpose of `const` appearing in the declaration of `a` is to forbid using it to change its target.

Comment: @Claudiu: let me add the following information

1) B is actually a container class I wrote (lets say a list) 
2) A is a class using this list
3) func1 is function that need to find if element T is in the list or not
4) func 2 is a function that recieves element I want to remove from the list 

saying that, isnt the parameter a in func2 has to be a const? 
because I need to declare I'm not changing it

Comment: @Jinxed: Ah ok, I think I understand. Check out my latest edit. You have to change `func1`'s declaration because it really takes something other than what it's written as right now.

Answer (score 6):

When `int*` is used to instantiate `B`, the function

```
void func1(const T& t) {}
```

is equivalent to:

```
void func1(int* const& t) {}
```

A parameter of type `const int*` is not compatible with `int* const&`.

You need to rethink your functions a bit.

**Update**

Use of `B<int>` instead of `B<int*>` in `A` might be what you are looking for.

```
class A
{
      B<int> b;
   public:
      void func2(const int* a)
      {
         b.func1(*a);
      }
};
```

Comment: Ha, it rather reminds me of stringing Christmas lights on a house for a few hours, only to realize you're done, and holding two female ends of the cord. So close, and yet so far!

Comment: @JasonMc92, I haven't had that experience myself but I can imagine the anguish :)

Comment: R Sahu: first of all thanks for the help but I already understood the problem and I'm trying to figure a way to fix that without changing the functions or using const_cast

Comment: @Jinxed, your classes and functions seem contrived. Is there a real problem behind it? Can you elaborate the real problem in your post?