# Operator overloading for << and >> does not work stream object in argument is const &

Tags: c++, class, return, constants

I have a confusion. I am making a set class and when I overload the << or >> operators with this prototype:

```
ostream& operator<<(const ostream & out, Set & argSet)
{
    //whatever my code does
    return out;
}
```

It does not work. But if I remove the "const" keyword in first argument, it works. I am confused why it is not working. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The `const` should go to `const Set & argSet`.

Comment: Think a bit about what's changing when you read/write from/to a string. The only constant is the written data.

Comment: Also, when you return the first argument, you would remove the constness. Const can always be added, but never removed.

Comment: @leemes that is not true.  There is `const_cast` which can remove constness.

Comment: @NathanOliver I meant implicitly, of course...

Comment: @NathanOliver but it is still undefined behaviour if you modify the object (or write through the pointer) that you used const_cast to remove const from.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I am using a function from argSet so I cannot and do not want to make it constant.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Only if that object was `const` to begin with.  see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357600/is-const-cast-safe

Comment: @NathanOliver You are correct. But that is often something that it can be very hard to know for certain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But if I remove the "const" keyword in first argument, it works. I am confused why it is not working.

In both cases (overloading `operator<<()` and `operator>>()`) for the `ostream&` and the `istream&` references the stream state is usually changed by the operations made inside, thus these can't be `const` references.

One obvious reason you can't do so, is the required return type that can't be implicitly changed from `const` reference to non `const` reference.

Comment: Hmm that's helpful. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

The stream cannot be `const` because its internal state has to be able to change upon insertion/extraction or other operations.

For instance, if it were to reach EOF, how would it set the relevant bit (`eofbit`)?