# Default constructor with constant members

Tags: c++, class, constructor, constants

I have a class in C++, say "Customer", and I want to have a member of it for ID,

```
private:
const string x; // Customer's ID
```

now the normal constructor would look like this:

```
Customer::Customer(const string& ID): x(ID){}
```

Now, I want to build a default constructor, without initializing x. Is it possible? Because if I initialize it to some random value, say "untitled" then I can't change it anymore because its a const.

So should I not build a default constructor at all, or is there a possibility of building one that doesn't initialize x and you can do that later?

Comment: All const members must be intialized in the constructor.  You could do `Customer() : x("Some default String") { }` but I don't know if that is what you need.  If you really need to modify it at a later time you could just not make it `const`.  Another **dangerous** option is to use `const_cast`

Comment: The conflicting requirements mean that the current design direction is ungood. What problem are you trying to solve by introducing a default constructor? A default constructor is often used to declare and later change an object, but you can't meaningfully copy assign a class with a `const` data member.

Comment: If what you want is a "const member that can maybe be modified later" you don't really want a const member.

Comment: I have an exercise in my course on OOP and for every customer there should be an ID, which you can not change at a later time (unlike her cellphone or address), so it makes a lot of sense to be const. Also I want to be a "professional" doing this and I understood defining manually a default const is a good habit, but it seems to contradict the assignment. If there is indeed no "legitimate" way to assign a default ctor to const members then probably I should not define a default ctor.

Comment: Not modified later, but rather assigned later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now, I want to build a default constructor, without initializing x. Is it possible?

No, it's not possible.

> Because if I initialize it to some random value, say "untitled" then I can't change it anymore because its a const.

That's exactly the purpose of `const`.

> So should I not build a default constructor at all, or is there a possibility of building one that doesn't initialize x and you can do that later?

Well, if `x` really should be `const` (which I doubt is actually needed), you shouldn't provide a default constructor, unless you could manage to initialize `x` uniquely from some `constexpr`.

Comment: Thank you, I need to learn more C++ to really understand what is kind of "professional" programming and what is really idiotic programming. The whole point of this assignment is how to be a "good" programmer and that's why I waste so much time on these things.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can modify it later (but that is probably not a good idea).  After you have thought about it for a good long time look at this code:

```
const string s = "";
*const_cast<string*>(&s) = "new string";
```

To use this in your code you could create a parameterless constructor like this:

```
Customer() : x("") { }
```

And then modify it later in your code:

```
*const_cast<string*>(&x) = "new string"
```

Although this might be a bad idea to do in practice.  You should look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/357600/6149078) for more info about the dangers of this

Another alternative to this is to create a cool struct:

```
template<class T>
class OneTimeAssign{
        T data;
        bool alreadyAssigned;
    public:
        OneTimeAssign() : data(), alreadyAssigned(false){ }
        void operator=(T&& newData){
            if (alreadyAssigned) throw "Error";
            data = newData;
            alreadyAssigned = true;
        }
        operator const T&() const{
            return data;
        }
        const T* const operator->(){
            return &data;
        }
};
```

You could then use it like this:

```
OneTimeAssign<std::string> Mine;
Mine = "First assign";
//Mine = "Second assign"; //Runtime Error
std::cout << (std::string)Mine << std::endl;
system("pause");
```

Comment: _`const_cast`_ Are you serious?

Comment: Well, the technical description is correct. But as you mentioned such stuff shouldn't ever used in practice.

Comment: The example is UB because it modifies an originally `const` variable.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf what is UB

Comment: @DarthRubik; UB is short for Undefined Behavior. Anything can happen, including nothing, or a crash.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf It does have that (but that is only a bonus)