# cast away constness to move class member

Tags: c++, constants, move

There is a `ThirdParty` class that has member variable `std::vector<T> vec`. Unfortunately it provides only readonly access to it: `const std::vector<T>& getVec() const;`
I have a temporary object of this class and want to extract this vector. Can I somehow cast away the constness and move the vector instead of copying it? Is it safe?

I have a source code of the `ThirdParty` class and can check for implementation details if needed.

Comment: If you have the source code, why not add a member that returns an rvalue reference to the vector so you can cleanly move-construct your vector?

Comment: I'd recommend that you just make the copy, unless you've already profiled and found this copy to be a bottleneck in your application. It's best to use 3rd party APIs as they are intended

Comment: @cdhowie, It's a huge library and I'm kind of afraid of changing its source code...

Comment: Very related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/357600/1896169

Comment: Who can say if it is safe without examining the third party code? The owning object may need all the bits left where it put them.