# Modifying the value of a user defined type in `std::set`

Tags: c++, stl, c++17, c++20, stdset

Consider the case where I have a user defined type with say a `id()` member function which returns a unique `std::string`.

I want a container of this objects, where the `id()` uniquely identifies the elements, but I want to "use" the objects to do other things which may modify their members.

I am currently constructing the objects.by calling `std::set::emplace` and capturing the returned iterator, bool pair.

But I am then not allowed to modify it's value as the iterator is const.

Is there a good way to do what I want? The only two I can think of are:

1. Store `unique_ptr`s to the object in the `set`, this way the pointer value is what differentiates it rather than the name and the object pointed to can be modified.
2. Store a `map` using the `id()` as the Key, but this means I have duplicated the keys.

I am happy to use well adopted and modern libraries, such as boost, if they have the right container for my problem.

Comment: Are you using a `set` to make sure you only have unique objects in the container?

Comment: @NathanOliver yes and also to provide a sub O(n) look time based on the key. I have the same issue with `std::unordered_set` too

Comment: If you are careful not to affect strict weak ordering, you might be able to get away with mutable class members and const class methods. This would be rather ugly, but it'll work. Same is true for `unordered_set`, as long as the hash value, is unaffected.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That is definitely not ideal as I am using const to affect for the real purpose of the type. I think the pointer route is going to be my best bet.

Comment: Have you considered use of the `.extract` member function to remove the desired item from the set, modify it, and place it back in?  This avoids all allocations associated with a "normal" insert.

Comment: Unless space is genuinely an issue, I would just use `unordered_map` and duplicate the key. I would have expected from your description and comments that you need to be able to lookup by the id string, so not sure how the pointer option will work for you.

Comment: @JohnIlacqua by using a custom hash or compare func which dereference the pointer and get the `id()`

Comment: @HowardHinnant, it's a consideration but the code starts to look very crusty. And it seems a bit daft considering it's hashed or compared value won't changed. I am definitely erring towards going with the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

> *Is there a good way to do what I want?*

No not really. The granularity of `std::set` is at object level. There is no way to express that a portion of an object contributes to the key.

Some people recommend declaring all non-key members `mutable`. This is wrong, as `mutable` is meant for things that are hidden from the public interface of the object (e.g. a mutex).

The "official" way is to take the object out the set, modify it and put it back in. C++17 has [`set::extract`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/extract) which helps to improve performance of this task a bit (which of course remains inefficient if you never modify the key, since the tree still has to be checked/rebalanced).

> *I want to "use" the objects to do other things which may modify their members.*

If you're absolutely sure you never modify the object key, just cast away `const`ness. From a legal point of view [it is OK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357600/is-const-cast-safe) to cast away constness from objects that were not born `const`. For extra safety you can wrap the key into another, `const` member:

```
struct Element {
    const Key key;
    Value value;
};
```

This won't help if you have a data cube with multiple sets each using its own "view" on the key.

> *1. Store `unique_ptr`s to the object in the `set`*

This would be a pessimization due to extra indirection. Since the elements are on the heap, you will take an extra cache miss. And again end up with UB if you accidentally modify the key.

> *2. Store a `map` using the `id()` as the Key*

Yes, different variations of this approach are possible, but you must still ensure to never modify the key.

For example you could store a key + pointer to data. This approach is often combined with a [dense_hash_set](http://goog-sparsehash.sourceforge.net/doc/dense_hash_set.html) with linear probing for best performance. Since the value is accessed only once after the element is found, it doesn't really matter that it is located elsewhere.

Comment: Reinsert an `extract`ed node with hint should be O(1), though of course you need to keep around the next iterator: `auto nh = c.extract(it++); nh.value()./* ... */; it = c.insert(it, std::move(nh));`

Comment: Yes, but O(0) (i.e. not doing it) beats O(1).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [Boost.MultiIndex](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) as a [drop-in replacement](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/techniques.html#emulate_std_containers) for `std::set`, as it adds the [`modify`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/ord_indices.html#modify) method which allows modification of an element, checking whether the position within the container has changed:

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>

struct S { /* ... */ };
boost::multi_index_container<S> t; // default configuration emulates std::set<S>
auto [it, inserted] = t.emplace(...);
t.modify(it, [&](S& s) {
    // modify s here
    // if the key is unchanged, s does not move
    // the iterator `it` remains valid regardless
});
```

[Example](https://godbolt.org/z/4N_c_g).

There is a small overhead in checking that the key is indeed unchanged, but this should be minimal compared to the rest of the program and should optimize and predict well.

Answer (score 0):

`std::set` maintains its elements sorted, and the *keys* the elements are sorted by, correspond to the elements themself. As a result, the elements in the `std::set` are `const` qualified to prevent the user from modifying the elements (i.e., the keys) and thus breaking the `std::set` order.

Traditionally, if you wanted to modify an element of an `std::set`, you would have first to remove the element object you wish to modify from the `std::set`, modify it, and insert it into the `std::set` again. The problem is that this results in the allocation of an `std::set` internal node.

Since C++17 you can remove and reinsert an element into the `std::set` without allocating an `std::set` internal node thanks to [**`std::set::extract()`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/extract). This member function returns the node handle corresponding to the requested element. After modifying the element through this returned node, you can reinsert the node with the corresponding `insert()` overload. No node allocation takes place as you are reusing an already allocated node.

The drawback to these approaches – regardless of whether or not allocation occurs – is that reinserting the element into the `std::set` takes logarithmic time in the size of the set (unless you can take advantage of the *hint* to `insert()`).

#### Casting away constness and modifying `std::set` elements

You can still cast `const` away from an element of the `std::set` and modify its data members, as long as your `std::set`'s comparison function doesn't take into account the data members you change. That is, if you only modify data members of an element belonging to an `std::set` whose comparison function doesn't consider, the order won't break.